# Using jquery and prototype

Tags: jquery

im using lightbox.js
it needs prototype.js and i need to use jquery.js. Now both of these libraries dont work together.
Can someone explain how to do noconflict?

The manual on jquery website said i needed to include the prototype.js right after i called noconflict within the script tags, im not sure how to do this.
these are the two files that need prototype

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery/lightbox/js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery/lightbox/js/lightbox.js"></script>
```

Comment: If at all possible, do yourself the favour and use only one of the libraries. There are many lightbox alternatives for jQuery.

Comment: When making a JavaScript question, it's usually a good idea to create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) test case.

Comment: @Inerdial: Generally that's true, but not for this kind of question.

Comment: Because the fact that he's mixing jQuery and prototype explains enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simply: Use a jQuery-based lightbox alternative. [Colorbox](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) is pretty good for example.

However, noConflict is pretty easy, too:

After including jQuery, run this code: `jQuery.noConflict();`. To keep using `$` in your code, wrap it with the following:

```
(function($) {
    // your code
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everyone elese. If jQuery is a requirement, then switch to a jQuery based light box. There are a TON of them.

That said this is waht the documentation means:

```
<!-- inc. jquery and call noConflict -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

<!-- inc. inc. prototype stuff -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery/lightbox/js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery/lightbox/js/lightbox.js"></script>
```

Comment: i switched to shadowbox which is jquery plugin :D